# I won't enable my location on the map, but, if the location turned off ,‘enable location service’ appeared

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Sometimes I wont enable my location on the map, but if location turned off and we call HuaweiMap.setMyLocationEnabled(Boolean value) then dialog appear - see screenshot attached. Why this dialog is displayed？
[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. So you already allowed to use location services on your app but want to enable/disable the drawing of the current location a user is positioned and get this pop up no matter if the location service has or has not been allowed before?

And if you hit CANCEL the location is drawn but does not move, or what do you mean by functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Enables or disables the my-location layer.

1.If the my-location layer is enabled and the location is available, the layer constantly draws the user's current location and bearing and displays the UI controls for the user to interact with their location (for example, to enable or disable the camera to track their location and bearing).

2.To use the my-location layer function, you must apply for the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission unless you have set a custom location source.

3.If you have set a custom location source using `setLocationSource(LocationSource)`, the HUAWEI Map Kit SDK will not check whether the preceding permissions have been granted.

4.However, you must ensure that the user has granted all permissions required for the custom location source. Please refer to https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/hms-map-huaweimap#setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)